# I get an error when I try to use ROW_NUMBER(), why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I'm trying to write something like this:

```
string AT2 = string.Format("UPDATE User_Info SET Admin = 1 WHERE (Row_Number = N'{1}'+N'{0}')", x, 1);
```

with this as well above it:

```
string cmdStr = "SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Username, Password, Email, Phone, Admin, id, ROW_NUMBER() as 'Row_Number' FROM User_Info";
```

I get this error:

> The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause.

Does anyone have any idea why? so I need to add something in my table..? or write it differently?

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User_Info] 
(
    [Username]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Password]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Firstname] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Lastname]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Email]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Country]   NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Phone]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Gender]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Admin]     INT           NULL,
    [id]        INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Username] ASC)
);
```

Comment: What *is* your database? What do you think `row_number` is?

Comment: I assume its like `.Rows[x]`

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.  Obviously, your code doesn't have a column called `row_number`.  But beyond that, it is quite unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have an admin page on my site. I want that the update button will run the query on every user that's checked and change its `Admin` value to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string cmdStr = "SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Username, Password, Email, Phone, Admin, id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Firstname) FROM User_Info";
```

You are missing the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Firstname)` **OVER()** clause.

If you want to order by id use it as `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id`) so the rows will increase with respect to Id ascending the same goes for any row you want to base your `ROW_NUMBER` clause.

So the update statement may like this.

```
UPDATE User_Info SET Admin = 1 WHERE id=

(SELECT ID FROM (
(SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Username, Password, Email, Phone, Admin, id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Firstname) ROWNUMBER FROM User_Info)) b WHERE b.ROWNUMBER=N'{1}'+N'{0}')
```

Comment: so.. I updated the cmdStr, and I updated the AT2, so its `string AT2 = string.Format("UPDATE User_Info SET Admin = 1 WHERE (ROW_NUMBER() = N'{1}'+N'{0}')", x, 1);` I still get the same error though

Comment: search about window function in sqlserver

Comment: I understand a little more now, but it doesn't help - because it seems like I have a clause (`order by`) and it's still telling me that I have to add a clause

Comment: On update you need to use the database column now like 'ID' you do not use the ROW_NUMBER column. I hope I got you well

Comment: So I can't use a column like `Username`? oh also if I use `id` - does it have to be the primary key?

Comment: Yes it needs to be unique, it doesn't necessarily need to be a primary key though. So the update statement may look like this Update  `UPDATE User_Info SET Admin = 1 WHERE id=

SELECT ID FROM (
(SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Username, Password, Email, Phone, Admin, id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Firstname) ROWNUMBER FROM User_Info)) b WHERE b.ROWNUMBER=N'{1}'+N'{0}')", x, 1)`

Comment: atm, got this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: I still get incorrect syntax near `SELECT` :O, maybe because I should put "()" around where there's `WHERE`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213768/discussion-between-gnyasha-and-kfir-ezer).